# Fo-Dicom addupdate,delete and search Header Tages

Tags: dicom, fo-dicom

Is there anyone who can help me to add update,delete and search functionality in Dicom header with fo-dicom. i want to save image pixel data in dicom header.

im working in https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom

In desktop c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add or delete DicomTags from a DicomDataset (a dicomdataset is a collection that holds all the dicomtags from the header) just use the mothods 
- DicomDataset.Add
- DicomDataset.AddOrUpdate
- DicomDataset.Remove
And to access the pixeldata take a look at the wiki of fo-dicom here: https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki. There you can see some descriptions.

If this does not help you, please specify in more detail what exactly you need. It would be a pleasure for me to help you.